# How to disable JBOSS-LOCAL-USER SASL mechanism in Wildfly 14

Tags: jboss, wildfly, sasl, wildfly-14, xnio

How can I disable JBOSS-LOCAL-USER SASL authentication mechanism in Wildfly 14 client. I have set the following property in jboss-ejb-client.properties:  `remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_DISALLOWED_MECHANISMS=JBOSS-LOCAL-USER`

Still, I can see that JBOSS-LOCAL-USER mechanism is chosen by the client, which fails as the client and server reside on different hosts.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the server configuration for local authentication. For standalone you'd execute the following CLI command.

```
/core-service=management/security-realm=ApplicationRealm/authentication=local:remove
```

This removes the local authentication challenge from the `ApplicationRealm` which is the default realm for applications.